# Unable to assign gkehub.viewer or roles/firebase.viewer to service account

Tags: firebase, google-kubernetes-engine, gcloud

I'm using a jinja file like this one

```
resources:
- name: some-role
  type: gcp-types/iam-v1:projects.roles
  properties:
    roleId: some_role
    parent: projects/{{ env["project"] }}
    role:
      title: some-role
      description: some-role
      stage: ALPHA
      includedPermissions:
        - automl.annotationSpecs.get
- name: some-service-account
  type: iam.v1.serviceAccount
  properties:
    accountId: co-service-account
    displayName: co-service-account
  accessControl:
    gcpIamPolicy:
      bindings:
      - role: projects/{{ env["project"] }}/roles/co_custom_role
        members:
        - "serviceAccount:co-service-account@{{ env["project"] }}.iam.gserviceaccount.com"
      - role: roles/iam.serviceAccountUser
        members:
        - "serviceAccount:co-service-account@{{ env["project"] }}.iam.gserviceaccount.com"
      - role: roles/gkehub.viewer
        members:
        - "serviceAccount:co-service-account@{{ env["project"] }}.iam.gserviceaccount.com"
```

if I remove the gkuhub.viewer segment it works, but when added or when used firebase.viewer I'm getting the following error

```
roles/gkehub.serviceAgent is not supported for this resource
```

I really need to assign the gkehub and the firebase viewer roles to the service account, is there a workaround to assign these roles? I tried assigning the permissions directly but they say they can't be included in custom roles

Comment: I think the issue may be that the `gkehub.serviceAgent` role is restricted to Google-managed accounts. What permissions from it do you need for your service account? Perhaps there's another role (or you can create one) that has your necessary subset?

Comment: Does creating a [custom role](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/creating-custom-roles) with the permisions you need on [gkehub](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/understanding-roles#gke-hub-roles) and [firebase](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/understanding-roles#firebase-roles) is effective?